# How can I automatically square-crop an image?

Tags: image-processing, batch, cropping

I have a large number of photos that I need cropped into squares,  the thing is I want to crop them "intelligently" so I don't end up cropping through someone's face if tha isn't necessary.   Are there any free tools out there to do this?

Comment: The only one I can think of is [Thumbor](https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor/wiki). Might be worth a look although it's meant to be used as a web service.

Comment: @alex I'd say that's a useful answer, post it as one.